# How to create a text field using D3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a text field with D3 without using the html.

These are some examples of creating a text field using html:
http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/9910343
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/10633704
But these are not what I'm looking for.

I can create check-boxes using this code

```
d3.select(#left).selectAll("div")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .append("label")
                .each(function(d){
                   d3.select(this).append("input")
                                  .attr("type","checkbox")
                                  .property("checked", false)
                   d3.select(this).append("text")
                                  .text(function (d) {
                                   return d.num;
                                   });
                   });
```

Is there a way that I can create a text field using a code that is similar to the one that I used to create check-boxes?

Thank you.

Comment: All you have to do is change the type of the input.

Comment: Thank you !!! I changed the type from checkbox to text and it worked. =]